# What pattern or (loops and patterns) can find all possible character in word and keep sequence of founded in LUA

Tags: string, loops, lua, match

I want to take each founded character in any word

`str = "ABC"
str:match("(A?)(B?)(C?)")` if u can see I don't know any character of `str`. but i wanna see them if they found.

but what if

`str = yyyyAyyyyByyyyCyyyy
print( str:match(?) ) -- like "(A?).-(B?).-(C?)"
--> A, B, C
str = yyCyyAyyyyByyyyyyyy
print( str:match(?) )"
--> A, B
str = yyCyyyyyyyByyyyyCyyy
print( str:match(?) )"
--> B, C`

the word can be in any variation, just any. Hoh to do that pattern or loop if patterns is useless. I am dumb give me just a working code =)

Comment: `print((str:gsub("[^ABC]", "")))`

Comment: but if `str="CAB"` your pattern return `"CAB"`, but I wanna get `"AB"` because `"AB"` is a part of pattern sequence `"[^ABC]"`

Comment: Why `yyCyyyyyyyByyyyyCyyy` should give `B, C`?  What is the general rule?

Comment: ok, we have  some pattern `(A?).-(B?).-(C?)` (it is wrong, just example) and have a string `yyCyyyyyyyByyyyyCyy`. So, pattern didn't find(found empty) `A`, it is goog because we have `A?` in pattern. Then pattern must find `B` and `C` with any range between them, but I think `A` cannot be in this range... I am not sure =) . so returned vars: a, b, c = {"", "B", "C"}